# CIA photographing detainees nak ed before sending them to be tortured

Tags: united-states, international-law, human-rights

[CIA photographed detainees naked before sending them to be tortured](http://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2016/mar/28/cia-photographed-naked-detainees).

- Is this a sexual assault?
- Is this by itself a torture?
- What should be done for this issue by the International laws (such as the *Geneva conventions*)?

Comment: I think the answers will depend entirely on who you ask.

Comment: If worse stuff than being photographed naked occurred, can you explain why you are asking about the naked photography?

Comment: It's violations of human rights according to the Geneva convention.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm you can ask about what you said :)

Comment: If the post were not too old to transfer, I would suggest migrating it to Law.SE.

Answer (score 2):

[SCOTUS has decided](http://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/05pdf/05-184.pdf) that Article 3 of the [Geneva Convention](https://www.icrc.org/ihl/WebART/375-590006), "affords some minimal protection," to non-signatories involved in a conflict.

```
     Is this a Sexual assault?
```

**No**, not necessarily. To be a established as [sexual assault](https://www.icrc.org/customary-ihl/eng/docs/v2_rul_rule93), all the following elements must be satisfied. Naked photographs for identification purposes would not satisfy **(a)**, because they are not of a sexual nature.

> (a) The physical perpetrator commits an act of a sexual nature on another, including requiring that person to perform such an act.
>
> (b) That act infringes the victims’ physical integrity or amounts to an outrage to the victim’s personal dignity.
>
> (c) The victim does not consent to the act.
>
> (d) The physical perpetrator intentionally commits the act.
>
> (e) The physical perpetrator is aware that the act occurred without the consent of the victim.

```
     Is this itself a torture?
```

**No**. The SS were not taken to extract information, a confession, as punishment, intimidation, or coercion. They would not be described as severe physical or mental pain.

> **Definition of torture**
>
> The Elements of Crimes for the International Criminal Court provides that the war crime of torture consists of **the infliction of “severe physical or mental pain or suffering” for purposes such as “obtaining information or a confession, punishment, intimidation or coercion or for any reason based on discrimination of any kind”**.[18]  Contrary to human rights law, e.g. Article 1 of the Convention against Torture, the Elements of Crimes does not require that such pain or suffering be inflicted “by or at the instigation of or with the consent or acquiescence of a public official or other person acting in an official capacity”.

```
 What should be done for the issue by International laws (such as Geneva conventions)?
```

The Geneva convention under Article 3 might possibly protect non-signatory combatants under (c) if this is considered humiliating or degrading. If the purpose of the photographs was for identification or proof of the condition of the POW before sending them off somewhere else so that it could be proved that no harm was done to them, then probably not.

> (c) outrages upon personal dignity, in particular humiliating and degrading treatment;

Comment: For the victims; It is not the issue that **taking a pictures is for mental pain**,  or **mental pain is outcome of taking a pictures**. In any way they suffer pain. specially for eastern people it is sometimes worse than to be killed

Comment: @user1 I understand this; judging from the article the intention was for the torture to be done by 3rd parties, and the photographs to show that the CIA didn't do it. Quite seriously, to an eastern person, is the humiliation more outrageous than non-fatal torture?

Comment: Not for *all* eastern people, but in some cultures baring peoplespecialy women is the worse torture. in Iraq for example, there was (Unverified) reports that some Prisoners with nak ed pic wanted their relatives to attack Prison and kill them in Prison.